# Get info from plist file

Tags: bash, osx

I need my script to get information from macOS. The information is located in a `plist` file in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist`.

The binary content follows.

`bplist00�_NSWindow Frame SystemProfileYCPU Names_344 284 751 520 0 0 1440 877 �]HV2J-en-GB_GB_4MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)
,6VYg`

I would like just to put in a text file what is in bold and italic here, between the parenthesis. I tried different methods found on Internet without luck.

Answer (score 8):

A `plist` file format is one of binary XML, plain text XML, or even plain text JSON. The `plist` file that was posted in the question is the binary XML format.

One way to produce plain text from the binary file is as follows.

```
plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist
```

To convert the file back to binary, use `plutil` as follows.

```
plutil -convert binary1 com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist
```

This would have helped to produce a better, plain text format for the question.

---

Assuming that "HV2J-en-GB_GB_4" is the right key, then the desired value might be acquired by using `PlistBuddy` as follows. Note that wherever whitespace is encountered, single quotes can encapsulate text.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :'CPU Names':HV2J-en-GB_GB_4" com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist
```

For the BASH script, one might put this value in a variable using command substitution.

```
model=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :'CPU Names':HV2J-en-GB_GB_4" com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist)
```

Afterward, the value is available in the variable, `$model`.